# VB import variable into MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to import to import the value of a field into a stored procedure and I can't find out how to do that. The field in VB is character and the MySQL field name is character_name. I'm new to VB, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 COMMAND.Connection = Mysqlconn
                COMMAND.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                COMMAND.CommandText = "Import"
                COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("Ore counts for " & Character.Text & " imported successfully"
```

)

```
DECLARE @importID INT
DECLARE @character_name VARCHAR
DECLARE @import_date DATETIME

INSERT INTO Main (Character_Name,Import_Date)
    VALUES (@character_name,@import_date)
```

Comment: Code would help of what you are STUCK on, also you already have a question you accepted that's already doing this, enlighten me by explaining the difference...

Comment: I'm trying to do it as a stored procedure instead of in the actual VB code. I added the code I have so far, I just need to know how to pass the field to the stored procedure.

Comment: Stored procedure that receives values have a parameter list. You need to pass the values for these parameters through the SqlCommand.Parameters collection. Could you post just the starting lines of your stored procedure where are declared the parameters expected?

Comment: Added the Stored procedure

Comment: I could take the time to give you an example, but it's conveniently located here...  everything you need and more...  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-using-stored.html

Answer (score -1):

Something along the lines of

```
Command.Parameters.Add("@importID", SqlDbType.Int)
Command.Parameters.Add("@character_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1)
Command.Parameters.Add("@import_data", SqlDbType.DateTime)
```

Search Adonet.
Find an online c#->vbnet converter.